# Disparity between Data Connection and Connect Identifier

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, database-connection, connection-string

I created a data connection to an Oracle Database from my .NET MVC 5 solution, I auto-generated a controller with views using the Entity Framework and when running the application I get the ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier. The connection is to a remote database. Why would a connection string in a data connection work, but running the application that uses the data connection not work?

```
<add name="BF_FORMS" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.BF_FORMS.csdl|res://*/Models.BF_FORMS.ssdl|res://*/Models.BF_FORMS.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=****.*****.****:****/BPMDVL;PASSWORD=****;USER ID=****&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Are you running the application on the same computer? If not, you need to install the relevant Oracle Database connector on whichever PC you're running the application.

Comment: The application is run locally on my machine.

Comment: Check out [Why do I get error "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"?](http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb00951.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my error was in some of the auto generated code in the config file. After reading this response to the Stackoverflow question:  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741961/net-entity-framework-with-oracle-11g)
I added the following to my web.config at the project level.

`<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <settings>
          <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN"/>
        </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>`

I got the error that says that duplicate entries cannot exist.  Which I then realized that Visual Studio had already created a similar entry which I needed to overwrite.