# Read Oracle data connection using Entity Framework in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-4.5.2, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have Oracle database 11g and I want to use Entity Framework to read data from it. In first step I am trying to establish database connection and get status if it connected. However I am getting following error;

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code
```

my connection string is as following;

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EBS_UCAS_DbConnection" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 193.00.100.00)(PORT = 1500)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = myservice)));Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword;Unicode=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

this is where I am trying to test code, where I am getting error

```
 public void TestOracleConnection()
    {
        using (var dbContext = new UCAS_dbContext())
        {
            var data = dbContext.SyncCodes.Select(x => x.SyncDesc).ToList();

            var xx = "dd";
        }
    }
```

### Base DBContext class

```
public class BaseContext<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext
{
    static BaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null);
    }

    protected BaseContext()
    : base("name = EBS_UCAS_DbConnection")
    { }
}
```

### DbContext class

```
 public class UCAS_dbContext :BaseContext<UCAS_dbContext>
{
    public DbSet<SyncCodesEntity> SyncCodes { get; set; }
}
```

### Model class

```
 [Table("SYNC_CODES")]
public class SyncCodesEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string SyncDesc { get; set; }
}
```

### In other project where TNS is working

```
 public string database = "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 193.00.100.00)(PORT = 1500)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = myserver)))";

   public void setConnectString(string username, string password, string database)
    {

        if (this.disposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("clarusOracleObj");
        }
        connectString = "Data Source=" + database + ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" + username + ";Password=" + password;
        try
        {
            dbConn = new OracleConnection(connectString);
            dbConn.Open();
            dbConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //reset the connectString and throw the exception again.
            connectString = "";
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Connection string copy from data property in visual studio and I use .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle

```
 Data Source=sittingbull.blackpool.ac.uk:1500/myservice;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Password=***********;Unicode=True
```

Comment: First question is what have you got installed re the oracle client on the machine your using

Comment: are you referencing your TNSNames file correctly and whats in your ODBC \ Datasources manager

Comment: also, this might be of some use to you http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/NuGet/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.net entity framework with oracle 11g](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741961/net-entity-framework-with-oracle-11g)

Comment: didn't mean to bombard you :)

Comment: I have install oracle client both 32-bit and 64-bit and I can add data connection from Visual Studio 2015 so I believe this is correct

Comment: I copy the connection string from data properties in visual studio and that also give me same error

Comment: ok, so im guessing you have a folder structure of c:\Orable\Client_1 and then a Client_2 folder structure too

Comment: TNSName I believe is also correct because it used in another project that is reading data however that is not using entity framework where in my case I want to use entity framework

Comment: Can you show me an example of your TNSNames.Ora file and also have you successfully connected via ODBC?

Comment: structure are    C:\app\KZ\product\11.2.0\client_32   C:\app\KZ\product\11.2.0\client_64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127873/discussion-between-simon-price-and-toxic).

Comment: the next question that I have is is the DLL referenced in the project and in the bin folders when the application is built

Comment: also, take a quick look here too http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48297_01/doc/win.121/e41125/featConfig.htm#BABEGGHD this might help you too

Comment: the TestOracleConnection class is in same project where I have DbContext base class and DBContext class, Entity is another project and main project is WPF in which App.config I have provided connection details

Comment: I am new to oracle environment and is this best way to use Entity Framework with Oracle 11g?

Comment: Oracle has always been a pain in my backside to be honest, happy never to work with it again.  EF is the way forward though regardless of the scenario. Did you take a look at the first link I sent (here again) http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/NuGet/index.html on how to set it up using nuget

Comment: Yes I am going through the link you send it to me.

Comment: @SimonPrice, what are you talking about **ODBC**? `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` aka **ODP.NET Managed Driver** is something completely different!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Iam trying to prove a connection can be made, but feel free to chip in with your own information

Comment: @SimonPrice, you don't need any `tnsnames.ora` file when you provide full connection identifier. `tnsnames.ora` file (and similar) are only needed when you like to use a connection alias.

Comment: ODP.NET Managed Driver does not require any further Oracle Client installation.

Comment: I have use with TNS, same issue

Comment: Can you please provide the full error stack to us.

Comment: I am reading on internet Oracle.DataAccess.Client vs System.Data.OracleClient and it seems not going to be straight forward.

Comment: i did some changes in connection string and now I am getting System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' with InnerException: ORA-00942 table or view does not exist however I select SYNC_CODES from TOAD and getting all the records, so does it mean my connection string is work???

Comment: I have found answer ... refer to my update answer

Comment: many thanks Simon and Wernfried Domscheit, you help to put effort in right direction, + vote

Comment: Yes, obviously you are connected to database. Please open a new question i case of further problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after long battle found the answer of my issue.

Because I am using in WPF application so in App.Config file define the data Source alias and TNS detail to oracle database that you are trying to read ;

### App.Config

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
 <version number="*">
  <dataSources>
    <dataSource alias="DefaultDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 190.00.100.00)(PORT = 1500)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = myserver)))"/>
  </dataSources>
 </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

and point the data source alias in connection string with username and password

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="Data Source=DefaultDataSource;User ID=myusername;Password=mypass;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

so now you can use OracleDbContext with DbContext class to reference this database;

In doing this implementation I have come across another error

### Solving System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' with InnerException: ORA-00942 table or view does not exist
```

this error happened to due to wrong schema pick by default, I believe it pick dbo where in my case schema is ucas, so I need to define schema in onModelCreating override method

```
 public class UCAS_dbContext :BaseContext<UCAS_dbContext>
{

    public DbSet<SyncCodesEntity> SyncCodes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("UCAS");
    }
}
```

and finally my test Connection class

### Test Connection

```
 public void TestOracleConnection()
    {
        using (var dbContext = new UCAS_dbContext())
        {
            var query = (from b in dbContext.SyncCodes
                         select b).ToList();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be the spaces in your TNS. Enclose it by double-quotes, i.e. try this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add 
       name="EBS_UCAS_DbConnection" 
       providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
       connectionString='"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 193.00.100.00)(PORT = 1500)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = myservice)))";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword;Unicode=True'/>
</connectionStrings>
```

or

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add 
       name="EBS_UCAS_DbConnection" 
       providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
       connectionString="&quot;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 193.00.100.00)(PORT = 1500)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = myservice)))&quot;;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword;Unicode=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```